# How to setup Windows to not put my external drive to sleep?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, sleep

Every time I use some external device (pen-drive or external HDD) on my desktop, after some idle time my Windows 7 puts it into sleep state, turning it off. Sometimes it sleeps and doesn't come back. Is there a way to configure Windows to avoid the sleeping of my external device?

Comment: I think that the advanced power option is working.

Comment: @KCotreau: Can you post it as an answear??? It solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go into the Power Options in Control Panel, then click on "Change Plan Settings" for your plan, then there should be an option "Change advanced power settings", then look under the "Hard Disk" and "USB Settings" areas.

This one may not be the actual answer, but set your "Turn off Hard Disk after" to never (set 0), but I think the real one is to set "USB selective suspend settings" to "disabled" at least when plugged in...but maybe also when on battery if you are using it that way when it happens.

Answer (score 6):

Windows USB are set to be disabled if idle to save power, you can disable this function by going to

- Control Panel
- Device Manager
- Universal Serial Bus controllers *(expend this)*

You should see a list of *Generic USB Hub*

Right click on each one of them and select Properties | Power Management 
and uncheck the **Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power**

Comment: It was already unchecked

Comment: This worked on my 2017 Microsoft Surface. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this piece of software: NosleepHD: http://nosleephd.codeplex.com/
It writes an empty file every minute.

Comment: Please read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance on recommending software in an answer.

Comment: maybe with such solutions you shorten the life of the disk, guess with SSDs this could be more important

Answer (score 3):

I'm encountering the same issue (Windows 8.1) and none of the "power setting" solutions worked for me.

I ended up playing a movie file, an audio file... anything that cause regular accesses to the disk.

For less overhead, it should be feasible to write some script that just regularly access the disk, before it goes to sleep.

edit: here is a quick script that does the job.

A blank file "mzt7dbs5ffxamzsj.txt" (just some random name) will be created (then regularly written to) at the same location as the batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET FILE=%~dp0mzt7dbs5ffxamzsj.txt
SET TIMEOUT=30

ECHO.
ECHO File: %FILE%
ECHO Timeout: %TIMEOUT% seconds
ECHO.
ECHO Script is running...

:LOOP
TYPE NUL > "%FILE%"
TIMEOUT /T %TIMEOUT% /NOBREAK > NUL
GOTO LOOP
```

side notes:

- I tried `DIR` but it didn't work as the results are cached. There should be some way that doesn't require to use a file.
- Resource of interest: [How to create empty text file from a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file)
- Debugging was easy as my drive spins down every 40 seconds >_<

Answer (score 1):

The power options or device manager options never worked for me with Windows 8, 8.1 or 10. Below is a simply batch script to do the job. Open a text editor, copy-paste the commands, change the drive letter to match your HDD's, to add another drive replicate the **copy**, **del** commands once more, save it as a .bat or .cmd file and double click to run.

```
@echo off
:start

REM --- Change the drive letter D below to match your HDDs. To add another drive replicate the copy and del lines ---
copy NUL D:\HDDActive.txt
del D:\HDDActive.txt

TIMEOUT /T 30 /NOBREAK
goto start
```

Additionally, you may want to see [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000322.htm) to run the batch file on startup.